# Why am I getting an error in 1:nrow(counts) : argument of length 0

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I am doing topic modelling using the `topicmodels` package in R. I am creating a Corpus object, doing some basic preprocessing, and then creating a DocumentTermMatrix:

```
library(topicmodels)

#Set parameters for Gibbs sampling
burnin <- 4000
iter <- 2000
thin <- 500
seed <-list(2003,5,63,100001,765)
nstart <- 5
best <- TRUE

#Number of topics
k <- 8

#Run LDA using Gibbs sampling
# Start the clock!
ptm <- proc.time()
ldaOut <-LDA(dtm.new,k, method="Gibbs", control=list(nstart=nstart, seed = seed, best=best, 
                                                  burnin = burnin, iter = iter, thin=thin))
# Stop the clock
proc.time() - ptm
```

Then I got the error in the last line

```
 #docs to topics

ldaOut.topics <- as.matrix(topics(ldaOut))
```

Here is the error:

```
error in 1:nrow(counts) : argument of length 0
```

I assume that this means that it can't count the first row. Is there any way to check that.

Comment: `dtm.new` is not created in the code you provided but is used in `LDA`. It would be easier to look into, if that object existed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but i have created that in the initial steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does topics() not already give you a matrix?

In any case, "argument of length zero" is telling you that object "counts" has zero rows.

Comment: Thank you. There was an error to calculate the counts. That is why I get this error.

Comment: @Hani What was your error? I failed to figure out the problem. I'm facing the problem. Can you explain it, please?